How does an operating system know about display resolution and pixel density?
How does an operating system detect what the resolution and pixel density of my monitor is? Do monitors provide these information through some kine of interface to a video driver and then pass those information to the operating system? My other guess is that, the monitor provides a unique name which then a video driver uses that name to get display information. Am I right?

@Gantendo Thanks. That answers my question.
